# replaceAll with innerHTML replaces characters in tags too

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wrote a function that highlights spectific strings in a text by replacing the string with the same string wrapped in a `span` element, and then inserting the result with `innerHTML` in the given element.

However since I work here with `innerHTML` and not `innerText`, if the string to replace is a letter which is in the `span` tag, the letter gets replaced too, leaving a mess in the text.

Here is an example I just wrote with my function:

```js
const strings = ['e', 'a'];
const pElement = document.querySelector('p');

function highlight(strings) {
  var highlightedText = pElement.innerText
  strings.forEach(element => {
    if (pElement.innerHTML.includes(`<span class="span">${element.charAt(0)}</span>`) && element.length > 1)
      highlightedText = highlightedText.replaceAll(`<span class="highlight">${element.charAt(0)}</span>`, element)
    //in case string element from array is longer than 1, so not important in this example
    if (pElement.innerText.includes(element))
      highlightedText = highlightedText.replaceAll(element, `<span class="highlight">${element}</span>`)
  });
  pElement.innerHTML = highlightedText
}

highlight(strings)
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: red
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
```

And here is my problem. If I run the function like this, the output is: `Loran class="highlight">ean>m ipsum dolor sit aman class="highlight">ean>t`, because the 'a' from the `span` tag (wrapped around the 'e') gets replaced too.

So I would be very grateful if someone had an idea on how to only replace the characters in the text, but not the HTML tags.

Comment: You could traverse the DOM and only operate on text nodes.

Comment: "...So I would be very grateful..." someone does have an idea. And his name is @TimDown, and he has a very useful library called `rangy`.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do here is split the innerText in array and traverse the array while replacing the found elements using the html you want. finally you join the array and replace the html in the dom.

Here is an example:

```js
const strings = ['e', 'a'];
const pElement = document.querySelector('p');

function highlight(strings) {
  const transformedArr = pElement.innerText.split('').map(el => strings.includes(el) ? `<span class="highlight">${el}</span>` : el);
  
  pElement.innerHTML = transformedArr.join('');
}

highlight(strings)
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
```

Comment: But if the `<p>` has a `<span>` in it, this will lose the `<span>`.

Comment: OP asked: "*how to only replace the characters in the text, but not the HTML tags.*" - and your solution it to completely remove all html?

Comment: It works very well, but if there is a string that is not one letter long like 're', this doesn´t get highlighted anymore, since it´s now an array with one character per element each.